# Webscrape prices by extracting values inside div class with Beautiful Soup, Selenium, and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get return the price of a product in a given size since they fluctuate daily.
I was able to get my code to work on a website that uses "a class" but I can't get it to work with div & span class.

Link: https://www.flightclub.com/supreme-x-dunk-sb-low-varsity-red-varsity-red-white-black-152127?size=9.5
Price: $550 (as of this post)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                              
import pandas as pd                                                                        

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/donlento7/chromedriver")                                 

products=[] #List to store name of the product                                             
prices=[] #List to store price of the product                                              
driver.get('https://www.flightclub.com/supreme-x-dunk-sb-low-varsity-red-varsity-red-white-black-152127?size=9.5')

content = driver.page_source                                                               
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")                                                      
for a in soup.findAll('div',href=True, attrs={'class':'product-essential row-fluid product-type-configurable'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'mb-padding'})
    price=a.find('span', attrs={'class':'price'})                                      
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices})                                
#df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')                                  
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Product Name, Price]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting EMPTY list because of that line.

```
for a in soup.findAll('div',href=True, attrs={'class':'product-essential row-fluid product-type-configurable'}):
```

There is no `href` attribute in `div` tag.

Change this to :

```
for a in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'product-essential row-fluid product-type-configurable'}):
```